# How to understand why I get EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION with bpy.data.scenes.remove (myscene)?

Tags: python, rendering, scene

I'm trying to delete a scene in which a rendering is performed and finished, I also tried to further put a `time.sleep()` of several seconds to delay the deletion of the scene with `bpy.data.scenes.remove(my_scene)`
This creates a complete crash of blender, I managed through a small video to grab this image with the error:

[image]

My code is quite complex and is also based on this [answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163950/how-to-close-render-view-render-after-the-render-by-bpy-ops-render-render) question:

I'd like to understand the possible cause so I can fix this problem and never have to deal with it in the future

Comment: Using any reference to, or within,  an object that has been removed from blender will cause the above error. Eg `loc = ob.location; bpy.data.objects.remove(ob); print(loc)` equals goodnight nurse.

Comment: @batFINGER I have several problems with this type of error.
How would you bypass this problem loc = ob.location bpy.data.objects.remove (ob) print (loc) taking into account that I need to have the value loc even after removing the object?

Comment: `loc = ob.location.copy()`  is described as an "unbound copy" _ie_ it is an instance of the value and  no longer bound to the location of the object

Comment: Fantastic I hadn't thought of that. Too many times I run into this problem. By the way, I think your answer from some time ago is worth to be voted as the correct answer, as it was really useful for me to find my bugs in the code, This question is not very popular, but I think your answer may be useful to some people